# Why need bind in setInterval with method function?

Tags: javascript

Here's working code sample:

```
function Drum(){
  this.noise = 'boom';
  this.duration = 1000;
  this.goBoom = function(){console.log(this.noise)};
}
var drum = new Drum();
setInterval(drum.goBoom.bind(drum), drum.duration);
```

If I remove `.bind(drum)` part from this code instead of '*boom*' I'll get '*undefined*' in console.
What's the reason of such behavior since `typeof drum.goBoom` returns '*function*' ?

Comment: Just to be clear, it's `noise` that is actually undefined in your example. Because `this` doesn't reference the Drum instance (I think it's actually the window instance it will reference).

Comment: yep, to Timeout object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation for [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

If you omit the `bind(drum)` then `this` within the call back will be something other than the `drum` object you want.

Answer (score 2):

> since `typeof drum.goBoom` returns 'function'

This is actually irrelevant. It's value of `this` keyword which is important in here. You are passing a function reference by passing `drum.goBoom` as the first argument of the `setInterval` function, without using `bind` for setting the `this` keyword's value manually the `setInterval` calls the function with global object as it's `this` value (context) which doesn't have `noise` keyword, so `console.log` logs `undefined`.